# Adding new entities in ANNIE gazetteer

Tags: nlp, gate

I am using GATE for annotating a document with ANNIE. I followed the procedure (given in 13.2.2 of GATE user guide https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html ) of adding new entry "wasim" in person_male.lst  through the gazeteer editor available in GATE. It adds thsi entry but do not create lookup annotation for that word in the text document being processed by ANNIE. 
Moreover i also tried to make a separate .lst file and even tried to edit the existing .lst file in GATE/ANNIE/resources/gazetteer but it says permission is denied to save in this position.
please help

Comment: Yes i was considerng the case sensitive case already...i thnk this is problem with GATE because it apparently adds an entry in .lst file through the Gate developer interface but actually its not added because it does not make lookup annotation of that entity in text.

Comment: However i solved the issue by making a seprate .lst file and  .def file .storing it another place and giving link of that grammer to a seprate gazeteer. In other word now i am using two gazeteer one with default grammer (.lst and .def) and other wid my own created grammer

Answer (score 2):

From your description "permission denied" is not related to GATE somehow. I think this is issue with your local system. Please make sure that you really have enough of rights to edit plain text file.
Also, as far as I remember ANNIE gazetteers are case sensitive. If you added a "wasim" value then only this value will be matched but not Wasim or WASIM.